# What's wrong with having plain old TCP / UDP sockets in browser's API

Tags: sockets, browser, tcp, websocket

What's wrong with having plain old TCP / UDP sockets in browsers' API?

I know that there's such thing like WebSockets (that is built via TCP under-the-hood) but hey, what's wrong with plain sockets? Is it due some security issues? If so, how WebSockets help to prevent them?